# Spring cloud aws not able to put files in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have an application that upload files to aws S3, from my local works fine, but when I upload the application to Elastic Beanstalk and try to upload a file the application fail and return me an error with the text 413 Request Entity Too Large. My application is with Spring Boot and Spring cloud and my application properties is:

```
cloud:
   aws:
credentials:
  accessKey: 'myaccesskey'
  secretKey: 'mysecretkey'
  instanceProfile: true
region:
  static: eu-west-1
stack:
  auto: false
amazon:
 s3:
  default-bucket: 'mybucket'
```

Anybody knows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your application configuration. The file size is larger than the server is configured to allow.

Check out [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/413-request-entity-too-large-error-with-uploading-a-file) link to see how to change the max request size for various servers.

Comment: I have just  solve the problem checked my spring boot application, I had an error which was that I sent the file to the server several times.